# Problema em Configurar API Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Galera não consigo configurar a API do Google Maps, já coloquei minhas keys e tudo mais mas não vai.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Simple Map</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
                   * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
         height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
      }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
         var map;
         function initMap() {
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 center: {lat: -23.574423, lng: -46.623515},
                 zoom: 8
             });
         }
      </script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Matheus, algumas perguntas (podem ser bem ingênuas). 

1. Você trocou a palavra `KEY` pela sua chave dentro do arquivo de importação?
2. Está mostrando algum erro no console? (ele pode ser um grande aliado para resolver)
3. Você liberou o acesso para qualquer requisição(referente as plataformas) dentro da interface da GCP?

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz foi eu que troquei a chave pela palavra.

Comment: Ah, ok. Não visualizei o conteúdo da edição. Obrigado por avisar.

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Answer (score -2):

Sugiro que verifique sua conta de faturamento para obter uma key válida.

Ao utilizar key's de terceiros, pode acabar não funcionando.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).